# bash: find a path to selected file

Tags: bash, find

My script calls a program with an input file located on the USB in the following manner:

```
vmd -e /media/user_name/KINGSTON/extra/vmdVIZU2 > /dev/null
```

To avoid put here the full_path_to_the_file I need automatically to find the vmdVIZU2 file and save the full path to it in the variable and use in the command in the following fashion:

```
find . -type f -name vmdVIZU2
file_path='found_path'
vmd -e $file_path > /dev/null
```

how could it be automatized to find the file path in a quick manner ?

Comment: you'll need to replace `.` with a starting directory that makes sense. Maybe `/media/$USER` or even deeper if you know some of this will never change, maybe `/media/$USER/KINGSTON`? If this expected to work in many environments (without always having `/media`, you can put those dirs also like `find /media /altdir1 /altdir2 ... -name vmdVIZU2` . Put them in the "most likely to match first" order, so you don't seach `/altdir2` unless you really need to. Good luck.

Comment: There is probably an option to `find` that will stop looking once if finds your file, but you'll have to do some research to find that.

Comment: great idea with /media/$USER, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

You can `file_path=$(find . -type f -name vmdVIZu2)`.

Comment: but how to indicate automatically the zone of search ?? I run it from my desktop and it does not find a file located on the usb

Comment: Do not use `.` or it will depend on your CWD. Use anything starting with `/`